# JS loading web fonts dynamically with ajax on click — not displaying in IE9, IE10, …

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, font-face, webfonts

I have this function in Javascript, …

```
$.getMultiple(font.src).done(function()
{
    if (!$('head style[data-name="' + font.name + '"]').length)
    {
        $('head').append(
            '<style data-name="' + font.name + '">@font-face { font-family: "' + font.name + '"; src: url("' + font.src['eot'] + '"); src: url("' + font.src['eot'] + '?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("' + font.src['woff2'] + '") format("woff2"), url("' + font.src['woff'] + '") format("woff"), url("' + font.src['ttf'] + '") format("truetype"); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-stretch: normal; }</style>'
        );
    }
});
```

… where 4 font-files are loaded, after I have clicked on some element.
The idea is that after loading the 4 font files, the css code should be inserted inside the head tag. There is a section on the website with text, that already has the right CSS declaration for the font, that is loaded.

… and it works fine in most browsers, but — guess what — IE9, IE10 and I think Edge 13 don’t show the webfont (They don’t show the targeted text on the website, in the correct and recently loaded webfont — they use the standard font).

So what can I do to get it working on that ancient browsers?

By the way … that is how the getMultiple function looks like (even if it doesn’t matter in this case):

```
$.getMultiple = function(arr)
{
    var _arr = $.map(arr, function(scr){ return $.get(scr); });

    _arr.push($.Deferred(function(deferred){ $( deferred.resolve ); }));

    return $.when.apply($, _arr);
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who runs into the same problem. I’ve found a solution myself.

Seems like IE didn’t like the way I’ve inserted the script.

This is how it works:

```
$.getMultiple(font.src).done(function()
{
    if (!$('head style[data-name="' + font.name + '"]').length)
        $('<style data-name="' + font.name + '"></style>')
            .appendTo('head')
            .text('@font-face { font-family: "' + font.name + '"; src: url("' + font.src['eot'] + '"); src: url("' + font.src['eot'] + '?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("' + font.src['woff2'] + '") format("woff2"), url("' + font.src['woff'] + '") format("woff"), url("' + font.src['ttf'] + '") format("truetype"); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-stretch: normal; }');

    // … show text with new font :)
});
```

1. create the style-tag
2. append it to the head-tag
3. add the css/font-face code to the style-tag
4. be happy

NOTE: the font-file-paths must be absolute in some cases

Answer (score -1):

You will need to make sure you have the font in the correct format for IE

```
  @font-face{
    font-family: 'FONTNAME';
    url('../fonts/fontname.ttf') format('truetype');
    src:url('../fonts/fontname.svg#FONTNAME') format('svg');
    src:url('../fonts/fontname.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/fontname.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    src:url('../fonts/fontname.woff2') format('woff2');
    src:url('../fonts/fontname.woff') format('woff');
    src:url('../fonts/fontname.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal
    unicode-range: U+0020-00FE;
    }
```

Look at these tools to generate everything you need

https://fontie.pixelsvsbytes.com/webfont-generator

https://transfonter.org/

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: I’ve tried your code, but it doesn’t work too. The style isn’t applied here … like before :(

Comment: Why would you downvote the only person who is trying to help you? So you are trying to set the font for the text after the site has been loaded?

Comment: i’m sorry. yes that’s what i want. I’ve found out now, that if I go into the "web inspector" and I change the name of the font-family and then change it back to the correct name … then it will work … so I need a trick with which I can refresh the font-family - name … tricky